# Elasticsearch groovy script to check parameter inclusion in array

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, groovy

I'm using elasticsearch (v2.0.0) for search in Rails and want to add to our custom script for scoring, but I'm either messing up the syntax or just missing something else entirely. It all works without the check in the script for the array, so that's the only part that's not working.

So for the index, `recipe_user_ids` is an array of integers:

```
indexes :recipe_user_ids, type: 'integer'
```

Then in the search query I specify the parameter for the script file and which script file:

```
functions: [{
  script_score: {
    params: { current_user_id: user.id },
    script_file: 'ownership_script'
  }
}]
```

And the ownership-script.groovy file:

```
if (current_user_id == doc['user_id'].value) { owner_modifier = 1.0 } else { owner_modifier = 0.0 }
if (doc['recipe_user_ids'].values.contains(current_user_id)) { recipe_user_modifier = 50.0 } else { recipe_user_modifier = 0.0 }
(_score + (doc['score_for_sort'].value + owner_modifier + recipe_user_modifier)*5)/_score
```

I'm not getting any errors, but the results don't seem to match what I'd expect when the `recipe_user_ids` array does contain `current_user_id`, so everything is falling into the else statement. Is it a type issue, syntax? Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the correct name of that field: `recipes_user_ids` or `recipe_user_ids` ? You have both names in there...

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the post, not the code! Edited.

Comment: Where does the `user.id` value come from in your script parameters? And what version of ES are you running?

Comment: It's just an integer id from the user model. ES 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to occur  due to mismatch in type caused by autoboxing.

The `doc['field_name].values` for field mapping `short`, `integer`, `long` types seems to be returning a  collection always of type 'Long' and the argument to `contains` is autoboxed to `Integer`causing `contains` to fail.

You could probably explictly cast `current_user_id` to the type of Long:

**Example:**

`doc['recipe_user_ids'].values.contains(new Long(current_user_id))`

Or better to use the 'find' method

`doc['recipe_user_ids'].values.find {it == current_user_id}`

Comment: I think you need to remove the parenthesis around the `find` closure.

Comment: @Val strange works for me ! what error is it throwing ?

Comment: you can keep the `(...)`, but it's not necessary in groovy

Comment: should be `.find{it == current_user_id}`

Comment: Thanks, will try guys!

Comment: Is the 'find' method faster than contains? Why is it better?

Comment: don't think it is faster but i don't think it would be  perceptibly slower. The reason i feel `find`  is better since it does not invole an explicit cast . Casting the parameter to  Long is an implementation detail and may fail if in future upgrades of es changes `values` to  return a  type other than Long collection.

Comment: So find would work either way, whereas contains requires the explicit typecasting of current_user_id?